# Brim around just one section

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, adhesion, brims

I'm looking to print this item:

> https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4274950

I want to lay it flat on the bed, 90° to how it's shown on Thingiverse. The problem is there's the one little corner on the end of the piece. When placed flat, this corner makes one side of arch. During the print, this section will build up to have much more material up in the air over a relatively small contact point, until the archway is connected.

I'm worried the section will shake loose from the bed. Is it possible to tell Cura to put a brim around just this section, and not the whole piece?

If I have to, I can edit the model the include 0.13 mm thick section there as part of the file. But I'd prefer to slice for this.

Comment: FWIW: I ended up [editing the model.](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4275592)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way to do that with Cura without breaking it up into multiple parts with different settings for each, but what about just enabling supports? You'd only get a very small amount of support material and it would act similarly to a brim to keep the small part from detaching.

Answer (score 0):

I would enable supports using "Touching Build Plate", and then place a support blocker over the portion that you don't want supports added to.

Comment: How will this accomplish what I asked? I only want a small brim, not supports all the way, and the rest of it already directly connected to the build plate.

Comment: If you add supports to only the arched portion of the model it will prevent the small section from tipping/prying until it is joined to the main body. The supports can easily be removed while easily allowing you to complete the print successfully.

Comment: That adds more material and print time than is needed. Brim is faster/cheaper, if I can do just that section.